# Flutter: Text overflow in appbar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have an appbar that looks like this:

[image: appbar]

The user can change the text in the appbar. However, a text that is too long causes an overflow error:

[image: appbar overflow]

I figured wrapping the specific `Text` inside a `Flexible` widget would solve this issue but I get an error that I could not fix when using the `Flexible` approach:

`RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#0ac34 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE`

Here is the working code from the screenshots:

```
PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight + 60),
        child: Container(
          color: getAppBarColor(),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Visibility(
                          visible: hasBack,
                          child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                                color: getContentColor()),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          title,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: fontSize,
                            color: getContentColor(),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Spacer(),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: hasSettings,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: getIconButton(context),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ...getExtraIconButton()
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

I want the text to be dynamically abbreviated with "..." if he is too long. A dirty fix was to use a `SizedBox`, however, I would somehow need the `SizedBox` to have a non-static width for it to work on every device.
How do I achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your **Text** widget is inside a **Row**, therefore wrap it inside an **Expanded** widget. You already have the **TextOverflow.ellipsis** on it so this should work. What this does is devote most of the horizontal space to it (without having to add a fixed width SizedBox or Container around it).

Therefore, remove the nested **Row** containing the **Text** and the back button, and just keep the outer **Row**; no need for the **Spacer** widget, so just use an **Expanded** widget around the **Text** widget and that should work.
This gist should point you in the right direction.
gist.github.com/romanejaquez/8f9c7b0cf2ceb873ddef5dd7a625b4ec

Comment: Using a `Expanded` widget results in the same error as when using the `Flexible` widget :/

Comment: Interesting. Check out this Gist (https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/8f9c7b0cf2ceb873ddef5dd7a625b4ec) run it in Dartpad.dev. It is showing the ellipsis for me. Would love to help you get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Will do! Glad the gist helped guide you in the right direction - cheers!